# React iterating through map on class based components

Tags: reactjs

I'm finishing up a starter course on React and trying to combine lessons. You can see from my code that I'm trying to iterate through the mealPics array to output meal rating cards. At this point, I have no errors in the Inspector, but I also have no output. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <!-- REACT LIBRARY -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.5.4/dist/react.js"></script>
    <!-- REACT DOM LIBRARY -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.5.4/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <!-- BABEL LIBRARY -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id='app'>React has not rendered</div>

    <script type="text/babel">

    class MealPlanner extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            var meallist = this.props.list.map(function(meal){
                return <div key={meal.id} className="dinner">
                    <MealPic mealimage={meal.img}/>
                    <h1>Meal Name Goes here</h1>
                    <p>Like</p>
                    <button>+1</button>
                    <p>UnLike</p>
                    <button>-1</button>
                    <div>Count Goes Here</div>
                    <button>Reset</button>
                </div>
            });
        }      
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='wrapper'>
                {this.meallist}
            </div>
        );
    }
    }

    function MealPic(props){
        return(
            <img src={props.mealimage} alt="meal image" className="dinnerimage"/>
        );
    }

    var mealPics = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Meal One', img: "https://static.pexels.com/photos/406152/pexels-photo-406152.jpeg"},
        {id: 1, name: 'Meal Two', img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/566345/pexels-photo-566345.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"},
        {id: 1, name: 'Meal Three', img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/605626/pexels-photo-605626.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"}
    ];

    ReactDOM.render(
        <MealPlanner  list = {mealPics} />,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is change :

```
var meallist
```

to

```
this.meallist
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-var-scope-issue)**

Comment: Hey Vivek. Thx! Gratifying to see that I was that close. Is the working demo you set up on stackblitz based on Meteor? (I took a React/Meteor course but it was too much too soon so I backed up). Also, your demo iterates through the array as it should, but mine only outputs the first one. Any idea why?

Comment: NM.I found the problem. I had all 3 items in the array with the same id.

Comment: @WillDove, it dosen't matter what are you using , if it works with simple react it will work with Meteor also, Please provide the working example of your code with issue, Then may be I can help.

Comment: Thx, Vivek. I have the code working. I was just curious about the Meteor aspect. No worries and thanks for your help.